# MySQL SUM a column IF with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

I have two columns, gain and bia. I can get a sum and my calculation using the following code.

```
sum(gain) - sum(bia) AS 'TOT YAC',
```

But I also need to do another calculation for the bia column where another column meets a condition (series_end='Touchdown'). But I want to do it without changing my original SELECT statement which is below.

```
SELECT possession_team AS Team, ball_carrier_receiver AS Player,

FROM plays WHERE run_pass='P' AND pass_result <>'S' AND pass_result <>'R'
GROUP BY possession_team, ball_carrier_receiver;
```

This is where I am stuck. Logically it would be something like below, but I can't seem to get anything to work in MySQL code. It can't be a "case when else 1 then 0 end" because I need a true sum of the bia column (values can range from -5 to 50).

```
sum(bia if series_end='Touchdown') AS 'BIA TD',
```

Comment: `SUM(bia * (series_end='Touchdown')) AS 'BIA TD'`

Comment: This works! Not sure how to mark this as a correct answer though.

Comment: This is common, base, expression, short form of "conditional aggregation" (search and study).

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you are asking you need to use a `CASE` statement

```
SELECT possession_team Team, ball_carrier_receiver Player,
SUM(gain) - SUM(bia) 'TOT YAC',
SUM(bia CASE WHEN series_end = 'Touchdown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'BIA TD',
FROM plays 
WHERE run_pass = 'P' 
AND pass_result NOT IN ('S', 'R')
GROUP BY possession_team, ball_carrier_receiver;
```